# R Shiny: Reuse lengthy computation for different output controls

Tags: r, shiny

I have the following code in server.R:

```
library(shiny)

source("helpers.R")

shinyServer(function(input, output) {
    output$txtOutput1 <- renderText({ 
        someLengthyComputation(input$txtInput)[1]
    })
    output$txtOutput2 <- renderText({ 
        someLengthyComputation(input$txtInput)[2]
    })
    output$txtOutput3 <- renderText({ 
        someLengthyComputation(input$txtInput)[3]
    })
})
```

helpers.R contains the method `someLengthyComputation` which returns a vector of size 3.  How can I get around calling it three times every time `txtInput` changes and only call it once while updating all three text output controls?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply place `someLengthyComputation` inside a [`reactive`](http://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/reactive.html) expression:

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
    someExpensiveValue <- reactive({
        someLengthyComputation(input$txtInput)
    })

    output$txtOutput1 <- renderText({ 
        someExpensiveValue()[1]
    })

    output$txtOutput2 <- renderText({ 
        someExpensiveValue()[2]
    })

    output$txtOutput3 <- renderText({ 
        someExpensiveValue()[3]
    })
})
```

`someLengthyComputation` will be triggered only when `input$txtInput` changes and the first of the outputs is rendered otherwise `someExpensiveValue` will return a cached value.

It is also possible, although execution strategy is a little bit different, to use a combination of [`reactiveValues`](http://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/reactiveValues.html) and [`observe`](http://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/observe.html).

If `someLengthyComputation` is really expensive you should consider adding an [action button](http://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/actionButton.html) or a [submit button](http://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/submitButton.html) and triggering the computations only when it is clicked, especially when you use `textInput`.